# When auto-hiding the [top] MacOS menubar can that area be used by applications?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I have "Automatically hide and show the menu bar on desktop" enabled:

[image]

The Menu Bar *is* hidden - but the newly opened up desktop area at the top of the screen (as shown in Red rectangle below) is not taken advantage of by any application window

[image]

I can not drag any window up to use the extra space either.  So is there any way to actually take advantage of that space in an application window?

I am on *Monterey 12.1*

**Update**  *Chrome* , *Messages*, *System Preferences*, *Webex*, *iTerm2*, *Safari* all exhibit this behavior that they will not use that vacated menu-bar area strip.

However I just realized *MacVIM*  **does** use the strip. Not sure what's "special" / different about *MacVIM* ..

Comment: *I can not drag any window up to use the extra space either.* I have no problem dragging Firefox 99.0, System Preferences, etc. windows up (MAcOS 12.3.1).

Comment: When I drag *any* window it snaps back below the level of the [invisible] menu-bar.  _Chrome_ , _Messages_, _System Preferences_, etc . I am on _Monterey 12.1_

Comment: Do you have a [camera notch](https://discussions-cn-prz.apple.com/en/thread/253366351)? There's a notch hiding app the performs as you describe is happening.

Comment: @user16145658 I have done zero customisation of the camera on the system and have not installed any camera related App's.  It is a work machine only and the camera is used for Webex and Facetime no more.

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this?

Comment: @user981916  It does not happen on my other mac's - and I've had several since then.  I don't know what was going on

Comment: Thanks @WestCoastProjects. It's a damn shame that I am not sure whats going on.